# selenium and gockodriver version

Tags: webdriver, geckodriver

When I want to use selenium,firefox and `geckodriver` to scrape something ,I meet with the question as follows.

So I google it,it tells me that maybe It's because of their version doesn't macth well with each other.but I change the firefox version from firefox esr 45.0 to firefox 47.0,it doesn't work.

My computer system version is Debian jessie8,and now firefox version is 47.0,geckodriver version is 0.16.1;Apart from that,selenium version is 3.4.3.(just as the following pictures show)

## code

[image]

## error

[image]

Comment: paste your code as text

Comment: ok ,thank you very much,I have resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work together. Let us know if that fixes your problem.

Selenium – version 3.4

Firefox – version 53.0/52.0

GeckoDriver – version 0.16.1

Comment: thank you very much,I change the firefox version to 53.0 and it works

Comment: @bwx.winner You could further show your appreciation by [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). :-)